# I have a text file with with 3 columns separated with : how to sort the second column by the last 2 digits of column 2?

Tags: scripting, sort

This is an example of the text file:

```
195.92.211.47:21029:400
195.92.211.48:21023:400
```

How can I sort the lines of the file by second column's last 2 digits? The second column is always five digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the second `:`-delimited field always contains five digits:

```
$ sort -t ':' -k2.4,2n file
195.92.211.48:21023:400
195.92.211.47:21029:400
```

The `-k2.4,2n` instructs `sort` to use the second field, from character 4 onwards (that's what `.4` does) to the end of the field as the sorting key, and to sort the input numerically on that key (the `n` at the end). To sort numerically on the *whole* second field, you would have used `-k2,2n`. We use `-t ':'` to say that fields are delimited by colons.

You can see that it's using the right numbers for sorting if you run the command with `--debug` (showing both GNU `sort` and `sort` on OpenBSD here):

```
$ gsort --debug -t ':' -k2.4,2n file
gsort: text ordering performed using simple byte comparison
195.92.211.48:21023:400
                 __
_______________________
195.92.211.47:21029:400
                 __
_______________________
```

```
$ sort --debug -t ':' -k2.4,2n file
Memory to be used for sorting: 2139060224
sort_method=heapsort
; k1=<23>, k2=<29>; s1=<195.92.211.48:21023:400>, s2=<195.92.211.47:21029:400>; cmp1=-1
195.92.211.48:21023:400
195.92.211.47:21029:400
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort -t: -nk2.4`

```
-t uses the delimiter :
-n for numerical sort
-k your key is the second column
```

The key definitions are very well explained in `info sort`.

> ‘-k POS1[,POS2]’
>
> ‘--key=POS1[,POS2]’
>
> Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between
>        POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted),
>        *inclusive*.
>
> Each POS has the form ‘F[.C][OPTS]’, where F is the number of the
>        field to use, and C is the number of the first character from the
>        beginning of the field.  Fields and character positions are
>        numbered starting with 1; a character position of zero in POS2
>        indicates the field’s last character.  If ‘.C’ is omitted from
>        POS1, it defaults to 1 (the beginning of the field); if omitted
>        from POS2, it defaults to 0 (the end of the field).  OPTS are
>        ordering options, allowing individual keys to be sorted according
>        to different rules; see below for details.  Keys can span multiple
>        fields.
>
> Example: To sort on the second field, use ‘--key=2,2’ (‘-k 2,2’).
>        See below for more notes on keys and more examples.  See also the
>        ‘--debug’ option to help determine the part of the line being used
>        in the sort.